# Qual a melhor abordagem para entidades destintas com informações semelhantes e também diferentes?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um projeto que consiste em duas entidades: aluno e psicólogo. Ambos tem informações em comum, como: login, nome, sobrenome, idade, contato, endereço. Ambas as entidades também tem informações diferentes, como: aluno: matrícula, curso, semestre de ingresso; psicólogo: registro, crp, etc.

A princípio eu não queria criar duas tabelas diferentes com as mesmas coisas para ambos, por isso abstrai ao máximo e criei algo semelhante ao diagrama abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, minha questão se é possível melhorar essa pegada. Como acabei criando duas tabelas para colocar as informações específicadas de cada entidade a tabela de cargos parece inútil.

Answer (score 0):

É mais ou menos isso mesmo, o termo para o técnico para a modelagem que você esta fazendo é 'especialização ou generalização'.

https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-9---generalizacao-e-especializacao

O detalhe é que você pode tornar o id do estudante, ou do psicólogo uma chave estrangeira para a entidade `user`, isso vai facilitar sua vida quando quiser pesquisar por todos os usuários, ou usuários com uma a outra característica.

p.s.: ia postar essa resposta como comentário mas ainda sou usuário novo por aqui.